# Error 503 Service Unavailable - PHP error with Yii 2 on OpenShift

Tags: php, openshift, yii2

I'm testing out Yii 2.0 on an `OpenShift` instance running a scalable app with PHP 5.4 but all i'm getting is a 503 Service Unavailable error.

Looking in the php log there's the following line but i dont understand what the problem is, and i was hoping somebody could let me know.

> [Sat Aug 16 10:03:38 2014] [error] [client ~ip~] PHP Fatal error: 
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/web/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/web/index.php
>   on line 7
>       - - - [16/Aug/2014:10:03:38 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "-"

I already posted this on the Yii forum [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/56846-error-on-openshift-503-service-unavailable/) but since on my local machine its working ok I figured that perhaps someone with more openshift experience might understand better the issue.

Regards,

Comment: Did you triple-check that mentioned file is really there (and it's readable)? For it's an `autoload.php` I assume this is a wrong path problem.

Comment: `i dont understand what the problem is` apparently the file `/var/lib/openshift/~instance~/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/autoload.php` doesn't exist or is not readable - error messages usually mean exactly what they say =). Did you forget to run `composer dumpautoload` ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That was it. Got intimidated by how long that error line was ;-)

Comment: So, it seems i need to do some reading on what this composer thing is cause i had a vendor and an assets folder excluded in gitignore. i got it to work by copying them to the server. However, if they are ignored in git there must be a reason and i guess i need to find this out too

Answer (score 0):

503 Service Unavailable means that the PHP app is not running, the app is not listening on the exposed service port, you must figure out why it is not running first, if the container restarts continuously causing you unable to proceed with the troubleshooting, you may start a debug terminal for the pod.